# check if a file is jpeg format using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I know I can use `file pic.jpg` to get the file type, but how do I write an `if`  statement to check it in a shell script?

E.g. (pseudo code):

```
if pic.jpg == jpeg file then
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try (assumes **Bash v3.0+**, using `=~`, the regex-matching operator):

```
if [[ $(file -b 'pic.jpg') =~ JPEG ]]; then ...
```

If you want to match `file`'s output more closely:

```
if [[ $(file -b 'pic.jpg') =~ ^'JPEG ' ]]; then ...
```

This will only match if the output *starts* with 'JPEG', followed by a space.

Alternatively, if you'd rather use a globbing-style pattern:

```
if [[ $(file -b 'pic.jpg') == 'JPEG '* ]]; then ...
```

---

**POSIX-compliant** conditionals (`[ ... ]`) do *not* offer regex or pattern matching, so a different approach is needed:

```
if expr "$(file -b 'pic.jpg')" : 'JPEG ' >/dev/null; then ...
```

Note: `expr` only supports *basic* regular expressions and is implicitly anchored at the start of the string (no need for `^`).

---

<sup>As for why `[[ ... ]]` rather than `[ ... ]` is needed in the Bash snippets:

 Advanced features such as the regex operator (`=~`) or pattern matching (e.g., use of unquoted `*` to represent any sequence of chars.) are nonstandard (not part of the POSIX shell specification).

Since these features are *incompatible* with how standard conditionals (`[ ... ]`) work, a new syntax was required; Bash, Ksh, and Zsh use `[[ ... ]]`.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Good old `case` is worth a mention, too.

```
case $(file -b pic.jpg) in
  'JPEG '*)
    echo is
    ;;
  *)
    echo is not
    ;;
esac
```

The lone right parentheses might seem uncanny at first, but other than that, this is reasonably simple, readable, versatile, and portable way back to the original Bourne shell. (POSIX allows for a matching left parenthesis before the expression, too.)

Answer (score 2):

For JPEG files, the `file -b` output has `JPEG` as the first word on the line:

```
pax> file -b somefile.jpg
JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, blah blah blah
```

So, you can use that to detect it with something like:

```
inputFile=somefile.jpg
if [[ $(file -b $testFile | awk '{print $1}') == "JPEG" ]] ; then
    echo $inputFile is a JPEG file.
fi
```

Comment: ++ for the detailed explanation, but using `awk` seems like overkill in this case.